# Access Database query: Calculate Price Change

Tags: sql, ms-access

I tried to use the following SQL to create a query to calculate price change in a order history table. Access give me a warning "At most one record can be returned..." and it returned one record with "#Name?" in every field. Could someone help me with this query, please? Much appreciated.

```
SELECT History.PartNumber,History.Datetime, History.Price, History.Quantity, (SELECT TOP 1 Price FROM History AS History1 
WHERE History1.Datetime < History.Datetime 
AND History1.PartNumber = History.PartNumber ORDER BY History1.Datetime DESC) as PreviousPrice, 
[PreviousPrice]-[Price] as PriceDiff
FROM History
ORDER BY History.PartNumber, History.Datetime DESC
```

I tested the following code as a subset of the query, and got the following error:
[Error dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLN5C.png)
after click on the OK button, I got this:
[#Name? in all fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKTgG.png)

```
SELECT 
history.partnumber, 
history.datetime, 
history.price, 
history.quantity, 
(SELECT TOP 1 price 
  FROM   history AS History1 
  WHERE  History1.datetime < history.datetime 
AND History1.partnumber = history.partnumber 
  ORDER  BY History1.datetime DESC
 ) AS PreviousPrice
FROM history
```

Comment: There is an example given on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa217680(v=office.11).aspx. I was trying to follow it, but couldn't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: column data type .......may be you use varchar in price column

Comment: Price is in Currency data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't calculate Price change on `PreviousPrice`,because `PreviousPrice` is a alias name on `select` subquery

using a subquery to make `PreviousPrice` column

You can try this query.

```
SELECT t.*,
       (t.previousprice - t.price)  AS PriceDiff  
FROM (
    SELECT 
       history.partnumber, 
       history.datetime, 
       history.price, 
       history.quantity, 
       (
            SELECT TOP 1 price 
            FROM   history AS History1 
            WHERE  History1.datetime < history.datetime 
                   AND History1.partnumber = history.partnumber 
            ORDER  BY History1.datetime DESC
        ) AS PreviousPrice
    FROM   history 
)t
ORDER  BY t.partnumber, 
          t.datetime DESC
```

I think you need to use `coalesce` function,if there isn't contain `PreviousPrice`.

```
  SELECT t.partnumber, 
       t.datetime, 
       t.price, 
       t.quantity, 
       coalesce(t.PreviousPrice,0) as 'PreviousPrice',
       coalesce((t.previousprice - t.price),0)  AS 'PriceDiff' 
FROM (
    SELECT 
       history.partnumber, 
       history.datetime, 
       history.price, 
       history.quantity, 
       (
            SELECT TOP 1 price 
            FROM   history AS History1 
            WHERE  History1.datetime < history.datetime 
                   AND History1.partnumber = history.partnumber 
            ORDER  BY History1.datetime DESC
        ) AS PreviousPrice
    FROM   history 
)t
ORDER  BY t.partnumber, 
          t.datetime DESC
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/52a7b/5*

**EDIT**

In my access this query work good.

If you want to add currency symbol on `PriceDiff` column,you can use [Format](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/format.php) function.

You can try this.

```
SELECT t.*,
       abs(t.previousprice - t.price)  AS PriceDiff  
FROM (
    SELECT 
       history.partnumber, 
       history.datetime, 
       history.price, 
       history.quantity, 
       (
            SELECT TOP 1 price 
            FROM   history AS History1 
            WHERE  History1.datetime < history.datetime 
                   AND History1.partnumber = history.partnumber 
            ORDER  BY History1.datetime DESC
        ) AS PreviousPrice
    FROM   history 
)t
WHERE t.PreviousPrice is not null
ORDER  BY t.partnumber, 
          t.datetime
```

**Source Data**

[image]

**Query Result**

[image]

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bfddb/6*

**EDIT#2**

I saw your source data,There are many duplicate `datetime` in your source data.you can't use `datetime` to be compare on subquery,otherwise there will be multiple row in subquery.

so you can compare with `ID` column,because It is your `PK`.

you can use `ID` instead of `datetime`

```
 SELECT t.*,
       abs(t.previousprice - t.price)  AS PriceDiff  
FROM (
SELECT 
       history.id,
       history.partnumber, 
       history.datetime, 
       history.price, 
       history.quantity, 
       (
            SELECT TOP 1 price 
            FROM   history AS History1 
            WHERE  History1.id < history.id 
                   AND History1.partnumber = history.partnumber 
            ORDER  BY History1.id DESC
        ) AS PreviousPrice
    FROM   history 
    )t
ORDER  BY t.partnumber,t.id
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bdeb91/1*

Comment: I was following the example giving here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa217680(v=office.11).aspx.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It give me the same warning and Access doesn't even change to Table view. Thanks for looking into it though.

Comment: @Max Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: For example, if History table has this data
    a1  "2018-04-27 4:00 pm" $500 2
    a1  "2018-04-27 5:00 pm" $400 2
The query should return
    a1 "2018-04-27 5:00 pm" $400 2 $500 $100

Comment: @Max I edit my answer, this subquery work good in my access you can try it.

Comment: I tried to run only the subset of the SQL command where t is generated (the part in the parenthesis). At first the table view will show data as the query is still running in the background. After about 5 seconds, it will pop up the same error message and all data changed to "#Name?". It is as if some data is triggering the error, but there are thousands of rows. It is difficult to pinpoint to the exact location. Any suggestions?

Comment: Uploaded to the original post.

Comment: @Max you edit query is work on sample data.Could you upload your access file `.accdb`,Let me figure out what is going on.

Comment: Here is the link to the test database: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ek6_Vc4SC4peEL2U1TGMcBFb7_3nf6u3.

Comment: Switching to ID field solved the problem!
Another question came: How do I limit the query to return only the latest pricediff (one record per partnumber)? Using Distinct?
btw, my original code also works after switching to ID.

Comment: If you want to only get latest pricediff (one record per partnumber) you can try write a subquery to get `MAX(id)` and `partnumber` then use `INNER JOIN`http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bdeb91/13